# Sublime text 2 unity launcher opens sublime.desktop

Tags: unity, launcher, text-editor, sublime-text

I have looked on various places but cannot find any answer to my problem. Here it is :

I installed Sublime text 2 following this tutorial : http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/ 
I replicated all the steps except step 4 that I changed by using this command instead : ~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop

Everything works fine apart from the fact that when I click on the shorcut icon or when I start sublime text with a command line, it does not open a new file but my sublime.desktop file.

Can somebody help me understand why it does that ?

Thanks in advance

Pierre-Victor

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made the `.desktop` file executable.

Run the command:

```
chmod +x /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

Comment: I ran this command as i did not but the .desktop file in usr/share/
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop

it does not change anything. When I click on the icon it still open the sublime.desktop file whereas i would like it to open on the where I was when i last left sublime. It might be a problem with what is in the .desktop file ..